# How to use netstat -b to find ip from .exe file

Tags: cmd, findstr, netstat

So I was looking for a way that I can use netstat -b and findstr. I tried using it in cmd like this:

```
netstat -b | findstr "chrome"
```

But that just gives me output

```
 [chrome.exe]
 [chrome.exe]
 [chrome.exe]
 [chrome.exe]
 [chrome.exe]
 [chrome.exe]
```

I want to get ip address as output within the "chrome.exe"

Comment: netstat will deliver the executable name as extra line not in the line with the actual netstat data. findstr is a tool that finds a line by data in the line and can't do multiline searches.  So it  finds the line containing chrome but the data is a different line. I don't see a way of doing it with netstat and findstr. Something similar on the powershell with the netstat equivalent get-nettcpconnection there and the more complete powershell featureset might get you something.

Comment: You could use netstat -o to get the processid (pid). The pid is on the same line as the ip etc. So first get all pid(s) used by chrome and then use findstr to filter by all found pid(s).

Comment: @Ralf I tried using netstat -o | findstr "13896", 13896 being my parent chrome pid, but it still gets nothing as output

Answer (score 1):

That could be done with a batch file with following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FileName=chrome.exe"
set "FoundExecutable="
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=[] " %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netstat.exe -b 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%G" == "%FileName%" (
        set "FoundExecutable=1"
    ) else if /I "%%~xG" == ".exe" (
        set "FoundExecutable="
    ) else if defined FoundExecutable if "%%G" == "TCP" (
        echo %FileName% %%H
    )
)
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `netstat /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `netstat` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Answer (score 0):

If powershell is an option for you, the command is quite simple:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -OwningProcess $(get-process chrome | % { $_.Id }) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

With this command you can get all PIDs by process name:

```
get-process chrome | % { $_.Id }
```

Then you can filter `Get-NetTCPConnection` (netstat alternative for powershell) by PIDs with a subshell.

Not all chrome processes have TCP connection established: to have a clean output `ErrorAction` can be setted to `SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 0):

netstat with the -b option displays the file name after the IP

For example:

```
TCP 0.0.0.0:123 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING
child_process_name
[parent_process_name.exe]
```

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) says:

> -b Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port. In some cases well-known executables host multiple
> independent components, and in these cases the sequence of components
> involved in creating the connection or listening port is displayed. In
> this case **the executable name is in [] at the bottom**, on top is the
> component it called, and so forth until TCP/IP was reached

Because of this, [the Mofi script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70701874/7250868) does not work correctly

Therefore, based on [the Mofi script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70701874/7250868), I made script that correctly displays the IP corresponding to the filename:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "FileName=chrome.exe"
set "FoundExecutable="
set "IP="

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=[] " %%I in ('netstat -abn 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%I" == "TCP" (
        set "IP=%%J"
        if "%%J" == "::" (
            set "IP=[%%J]%%K"
        ) else (
            set "IP=%%J"
        )
    ) else if /I "%%I" == "%FileName%" (
        set "FoundExecutable=1"
    ) else if /I "%%~xI" == ".exe" (
        call :reset
    )
    
    if defined IP if defined FoundExecutable (
        echo %FileName% !IP!
        call :reset
    )
)

:reset
set "IP="
set "FoundExecutable="
goto :eof

endlocal
```